# Icom RS-MS3W setup

Tags: icom, d-star

I am trying to use terminal mode for the first time on my Icom ID-52A.  I am already registered on DStar (through the UTRUST/national site, not a specific repeater).  I am trying to understand what the various RS-MS3W fields mean but the instructions are of little help.

Where do I get a domain name/ip for the gateway repeater?  I'm a not registered with a specific repeater (I registered with the nation dstar website).  I know a local repeater's dashboard is visible at BB2BBB.dstargateway.org, can I use that?  (It seems to resolve to the IP of a local repeater)

For terminal/AP callsign, I assume I put my call sign like "AA1AA I" (where I is a random suffix I picked)

After that, all attempts to transmit say:

```
RPT1: Failed to connect to network
RPT2: Failed to connect to network
UR:         I
MY: AA1AA
```

then the screen goes back to

```
RPT2: AA1AA I
RPT1: AA1AA G
UR: AA1AA 
MY: AA1AA
```

I confirmed my firewall is not blocking any ports.

Answer (score 0):

The domain/IP you need is that of the gateway software of a repeater on the D-Star network.

I haven't found a uniform way to find the IP, other than to peep at the logs on my hotspot (have done on my pi-star powered zumspot, as well via the status screen of my openspot3).

This IP address then goes into the `Gateway Repeater (Server IP/Domain)` field of the GUI.

Your call sign and a module letter of your choice then goes in the `Terminal/AP Call sign` field... make sure to pad this with spaces between your call sign and module number so that it's exactly 8 characters long. If your call sign is w7abc and the module letter you've chosen is B, then this entry would look like `W7ABC  B` which is 5 character call sign + 2 spaces + 1 module letter == 8 characters total.

You can experiment to see if the `Gateway Type` radio button matters for you, I only have tried `Global` since it works and I'm not in `Japan`.

Then, make sure your com port is correctly selected after plugging in the `OPC-2350LU` dongle that came with your radio, and put your radio into `Terminal Mode` (Menu -> DV Gateway -> Terminal Mode).

Now in terminal mode you no longer have any option to set the `FROM` to anything other than your call sign... which makes sense since terminal mode is all about using your radio as the `FROM` device.